# What could be a reason for a do try catch issue with contentsOfFile in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

I recently converted the syntax of a project I was working on from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 and am running into some issues with taking the contents of a txt file and converting them into a string. Everything works fine on old txt files in my project but new txt files are failing in the try portion of my code.

I'm not super familiar with how try/catch works but I've tested the code and on files that don't work the catch portion of my code is running so I'm assuming that the try part is failing in those cases. Is this some sort of bug or something that changed in Swift 3? I've checked the new files and they are txt files, formatted exactly the same way as the working txt files so I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)


        print(contents)


        textView.text = contents
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded

        print(error)

    }
} else {
        print("No contents found")
}
```

Error Message with encoding parameter:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “35 IAC 14 - Indiana State Teachers' Retirement Fund.txt” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/graysonfaircloth/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/(removed-numbers)/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/(removed-numbers)/CCHA-test-app.app/35 IAC 14 - Indiana State Teachers' Retirement Fund.txt, NSStringEncoding=4}

Error Message without encoding parameter:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “35 IAC 14 - Indiana State Teachers' Retirement Fund.txt” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/graysonfaircloth/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/(removed-numbers)/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/(removed-numbers)/CCHA-test-app.app/35 IAC 14 - Indiana State Teachers' Retirement Fund.txt}

Comment: Why do you print just *Help* instead of displaying the actual error?

Comment: Perhaps the file does not exist at that location, or is not readable? Or its contents is not valid UTF-8? Don't guess, `print(error)` in the error case!

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to include the error message. This leads me to believe that there is some problem with the file, but I've examined the files and couldn't find any problems.

Comment: Run Terminal and go to the folder containing the text file. Type the command `file 35 IAC 14 - Indiana State Teachers' Retirement Fund.txt`. The output of the `file` command should tell you what the file encoding is.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! I've learned the files that aren't loading are ISO-8859 text files. I haven't been able to figure out why they are encoded this way however. I am downloading files from Dropbox uploaded by some else. Is there any way to change these files into something that Swift can read?

Comment: Either convert the file to UTF-8 using something like TextEdit or update your code to specify the proper encoding. ISO-8859 files would require the `isoLatin1` (assuming the file is ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Was able to get it working by using isoLatin1. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

In Swift 3 we have extended using throwing, I think it's better then handling error.

**You need to check is your file included into build

and check name of file.**

Also you can print your path and check manually is your file added to build (simulator).

Comment: Since the code is getting into the `do/catch` it is clear that a file does actually exist at the path.